# nginx not serving admin static files?

Tags: django, nginx

***Clarification***: *The following error is onlyfor the **admin static files**, i.e. it is specific to the static files corresponding to the Django admin. The rest of the static files are working perfectly.*

#### Problem

Basically, I cannot access the **admin static files** using the ngix server.

It does work with the micro server of Django, and the `collectstatic` is doing its job, meaning it is putting the files on the expected place in the static folder.

The urls are correct but I cannot access the **admin static files** directly, but the others I can. So, for example:

1. I am able to access this url (copying it in the browser):
   `myserver.com:8080/static/css/base/base.css`
2. but I am not able to access this other url (copying it in the browser):
   `myserver.com:8080/static/admin/css/admin.css`

---

### What have I tried?

It **does work** if I copy the `admin/` directory structure into `__other_admin_directory_name/__`, and then I access
`myserver.com:8080/static/__other_admin_directory_name__/css/admin.css`

Moreover,

1. I checked permissions and everything is fine.
2. I tried to change ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/' to ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/**other_admin_directory_name**/', it doesn't work.

Finally, and it seems to be an important clue:

I tried to copy the `admin/` directory structure into `__admin_and_then_any_suffix/__`. Then I cannot access
`myserver.com:8080/static/__admin_and_then_any_suffix/__/css/admin.css`. So, if the name of the directory starts with `admin` (for example administration or `admin2`) then **it doesn't work**.

---

**EDIT - added thanks to @sarnold observation:**

The problem seems to be in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

```
location /static/admin {
   alias /home/vl3/.virtualenvs/vl3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the relevant portions of your `nginx` configuration.

Comment: This is a clean ubuntu 11.10 installation (it was working before in the same clean version) and I haven't touch the conf file but it seems you are right. There is something that seems to be the problem. I am editing my question...

Comment: @Carsten, maybe your link is wrong. [link](serveroverflow.com) does not exist

Comment: Is there a reason you need a specific location entry just for `/static/admin`? Wouldn't the standard '/static' cover it all? I just use a single: `location /static/  { alias /path/to/static/; }`

Comment: ok, i did the obvious here. I changed the path to the exact directory I have the files. It worked but I am worried, I don't think that is a line I should arbitrary change. This is a default configuration. I'll let you know exactly what is happening. Thanks!

Comment: ok, the directory that is created automatically is just wrong, instead of ...python2.7/site-packages/...static/, it should be ...python2.7/site-packages/...static/media/

Comment: You shouldn't be needing to reference into your python site-packages location. Are you collecting your static files there? What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My suggestions:

1. Use django 1.3+ (and [ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin))
2. Set both [`STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell) in your settings.py
3. Define just a single static entry in your nginx conf (with trailing slashes). ***No need*** for a second one that addresses `static/admin/`:

   ```
   location /static/  {
           alias /path/to/static/;
   }
   ```
4. Use `collectstatic` which should collect admin -> static/admin. It will live under the same location as all the rest of your collected static media.

   `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I am using django 1.4. I have the three of them: ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX, STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT. The collectstatic is working well as I explained. The only thing I am still curious about is where that ...python2.7/site-packages/...static/ came from...

Comment: Well you can get rid of ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX. Its no longer in use. That and the reference to the site-packages is all OLD django stuff. Its not used in 1.3+. admin will end up in the static root.

Comment: perfect! As I said this was a clean ubuntu 11.10 / nginx installation. Do you mind to do a small edition in your answer adding another step: delete the location __/static/admin/ { ... }__ section

Comment: Why? Did your default nginx conf somehow come with that entry in the first place? I was listing sort of a ground up set of items that would apply to anyone. If it isn't there then you probably shouldn't have it.

Comment: well, that's exactly what i mean. This is a clean installation. I never touched that file before. I solved the problem deleting that section in the file.

Comment: I did all of these and its still not working. However for the nginx config I have to use `root /usr/local/bin/apps/my-app-dir/;` since the `alias` config you list does not work. Using nginx 1.15.1, django 2.2.1. I can actually navigate to the CSS page too (view-source:http://myserver.com:1234/static/admin/css/base.css) and see the file contents, but it does not work on the actual admin site, the CSS does not display.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. My nginx server on Centos 7.6 can't access to static folder in path `/home/user/app/mysyte/static/`. In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` same error

```
open() "/home/user/app/mysyte/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

For solving and understanding this problem `:=*`

1. run command `getenforce`
2. if enforcing - `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx`

for me string with errrors looks like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=564f710dd55d a1=800 a2=0 a3=68632f656d6f682f items=0 ppid=7757 pid=7758 auid=4294967295 uid=998 gid=996 euid=998 suid=998 fsuid=998 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

copy id of audit msg `1558033633.723:201`

3. run command `grep yours_audit_id /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why`

output for me

```
[root@uwsgi ~]# grep 1558034479.384:221 /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
type=AVC msg=audit(1558034479.384:221): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

        Was caused by:
        The boolean httpd_read_user_content was set incorrectly.
        Description:
        Allow httpd to read user content

        Allow access by executing:
        # setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

So as you can see answer here `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1` when you run this command you see your static content